# How to change doctype to standards mode without having access to the code?

Tags: asp.net, css, internet-explorer, doctype, quirks-mode

I am designing a site based a .NET software CMS solution that doesn't follow current best practices. It uses tables and a doctype of `<!-- DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"  -->`. The software company doesn't let you edit `.aspx` files or `js`.  They only let you edit the stylesheet and different modules, e.g. HTML module, weather module, slideshow module, etc.

Thus, IE always renders the site in quirks mode breaking the CSS.  I do not have access to change the doctype or edit anything in `<head></head>`.

Is there a way to change the doctype without being able to access the code?

What I have to deal with:

```
<!--DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" -->
<html>
<head id="htmlHead"><title>
Welcome to xxx
</title>

<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
        function stopError()
        {
          return true;
        }
        window.onerror = stopError;
</script>

<link href="xxx.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<meta name="ROBOTS" content="INDEX,NOFOLLOW" />
<link href="xxx/favicon.ico" rel="SHORTCUT ICON" />
<style id="spMenuStyle"></style>
<link id="ApplicationRoot" rel="AppRoot" href="/xxx/" /><script type="text/javascript" src="/xxx/scripts/Utility.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" sr="cxxx/BlockIFrame.js">
</script>
<link href="/xxx/WebResource.axd?d=9IeP9KvvsN3Ik1tvDsOJspkYjKE_KnZBT8bvXX7faYYRqxbjgHhLZKgtKfFSoL4-itgpmZrgTG68lyrA-SRm95xnEdLdUHa4j1nbnB_xoc_0zNWbtGMRDJOai6Kgu4UI0Dg5lw2&amp;t=634950712700000000" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" class="Telerik_stylesheet" />
</head>
```

Comment: The construct in the first line of the code is not a doctype at all; it is simply a comment.

Comment: Exactly! I can't uncomment it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're able to inject your own JavaScript you might be able to inject the `X-UA-Compatible` meta tag.

This code will inject the meta tag and force IE to run in *edge* mode, which means IE will treat it as standards mode:

```
var meta = document.createElement('meta');
meta.setAttribute('http-equiv', 'x-ua-compatible');
meta.setAttribute('content', 'IE=edge');

document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);
```

[You can learn about the meta tag here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: The question says “The software company doesn't let you edit .aspx files or js”, but perhaps a `script` element could be inserted. However, it is possible that such an element, when inserted in the HTML code, would be stripped off by the CMS.

Comment: D'oh I completely missed that JS can't be modified. Without any code changes it'll probably not be possible

Comment: This is the best try.  Thanks anyway.